# How to clear terminal in C without using #include?

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I want to clear terminal in C without using #include.

Here is my code:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);

int main()
{
    printf("%c2J", 27);
}
```

Comment: What does "without #include" mean here (what does `#include` have to do with clearing the terminal)?

Comment: I don't think you understand what `#include` does. I suggest understanding that first, and then you will realize why this question either has no answer or a very trivial answer (depending on what you actually want).

Comment: You want `printf("\033[H\033[J");` and since you are already providing a prototype for `printf`, there is no need to include `stdio.h`

Comment: @DavidRanieri Thank you. You could answer my question.

Comment: @DavidRanieri but he wants own function (probably OP thinks that .h is a library which is very common beginner misunderstanding). He should compile with `-nostdlib`

Comment: C Programming Language hasnt any native command or function for this. you have to use Standarfd Librariries

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. I don't want to avoid using functions. I want to avoid using #include.

Comment: WHY do you want to avoid using #include? There is no good reason to do so. You asking this question indicates a serious problem. Tell us why.

Answer (score 1):

You likely won't be able to clear a terminal without using functions in the standard library, but probably the *closest* thing would be to use ANSI escape sequences, which *might* work depending on your terminal.

You'll have to output \x1b[2J (probably followed by \x1b[H).  These are the ANSI terminal escape sequences for clearing the screen and repositioning the cursor in the upper left "home" position, respectively.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {
    printf("\x1b[2J\x1b[H");
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that even if you specify the function prototype for `printf()`, as you have done above, you are still using the standard library and not making your own.  I can only think of one reason you'd ever want to do that: to make a quine fit on one line.

Comment: No real need for raw mode, the ANSI escapes in the `printf()` format string work fine.

Comment: You are using #include.

Comment: @Programmer: Yes, as I said, what you are asking either makes no sense (you want to use the standard library without header files? but that's not "mak[ing] [your] own function") or cannot be done in C. You will have to learn assembler language for your architecture if you want to, e.g., make your own `write()` or `printf()` functions.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Edited appropriately

Comment: Yes, it is ANSI. But why are you using #include? You can remove `#include <studio.h>` and change it to `int printf(const char *format, ...);`. After that, I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your own function you should not be using the **standatd library**. Invlude does not matter as `.h` files are not libraries. You should compile the code with `-nostdlib` option and write your own function.

In your code you simply use the standard library function - not your own one.